# Is this an isolation valve?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, faucet

I'm trying to change the kitchen tap in my apartment, but I'm struggling to stop the water supply to the existing tap. I have flexi pipes installed so I'm assuming I also have an isolation valve, but from all the pictures/videos I've seen they don't seem to be so I'm really confused.

I don't want to force anything, so I haven't tested it yet, but is it possible to stop the water in this set up?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no valves in that picture.

Comment: oh right haha, I have no idea about plumbing, I just thought where the copper and flexi pipes meet was a valve. I assumed because they left a square cutout on the backboard (fixed in)  that they would be what you'd use to stop the flow. So are you saying from what the pictures show, it isn't possible to stop the water?

Comment: A valve is going to have something on it that turns.  Like a handle or in some cases a slot for a screw driver (not common).  You just have pipes.

Comment: Why the square hole? Because it's cheap. Why no valves? Because it's cheap. There is no way to turn off the water from what you have pictured.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have any isolation valves in the picture you included. They would look something like this:
[image]

You probably have a cutoff to your unit but you'd have to check with your landlord. Be careful not to mess with the fittings until you determine where the cutoff is and who it affects, it could be for the entire building.